# 2d FFT on solar data

Tags: matlab, 2d, fft

I have a huge array of high frequency (1 Hz) solar irradiance data taken by about 50  pyranometers evenly distributed over a square mile. (For clarity, that's 50 data points per second total). I'm interested in "focusing" the image of the sun using the 2D FFT. I'm wondering if 1) This is possible 2) If it even makes sense. 
I spoke to a radar analyst who seemed to indicate that it's possible to use these pryranometers as a pseudo-camera. To test this, I formatted the data in Matlab such that each second of data is spatially laid out in a matrix that corresponds to the physical location of the data stations. From there, I use fft2 on each one second "frame", shift it, take the absolute value, take the log, use mat2gray and then plot with a heatmap.

[image: 2D FFT of solar data in a one second frame]

Any advice for this? Am I barking up the right tree?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are doing, I think you are barking up the wrong tree. You can use FFT for "focusing" (or tracking) when there is a correlation between signals on the time scale of your measurement. Since you have a data point every second, and you are only covering a square mile, and the speed of light is 186 thousand miles per second, your method doesn't stand a chance.

Something like this works when the frequency content of the measurement is high enough that you see meaningful phase shifts across your array. You see this with ultrasound or astrophysics (radio telescopes), for example - or any other "phased array" application. But with the time scale of your sampling, any fluctuations in the sun intensity will arrive "simultaneously" on all channels. If you sampled every 10 ns or so, you would see a difference in time of arrival of solar radiation for different detectors.

So I'm afraid the answer to your questions is "find a different approach", and "no".

A different approach might be this: If you need to know the direction of the sun, point the sensors in different directions; you will find a maximum in intensity for the one pointing most directly at the sun.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm less interested in solar tracking and more interested in clouds. Over a square mile, clouds begin to really matter. For a one sensor system, clouds show up as lower intensity on the pyranometer. The same is true for this multi-pyranometer system, but not all sensors will be effected. The time scale of the clouds moving across the field is probably in the 10 minute range, depending on the winds. We can actually "see" clouds move across the array on a heatmap plot, where the intensities are much lower in one region, then move across.

Comment: Clearly you will be able to "see" clouds with your array; but how does it relate to your comment about "focusing on the sun"? Perhaps a little more detail on what you are trying to do with the information will help us think along and give you actionable ideas.

Comment: I apologize, FFTs on this type of data are not my line of work. It was my understanding based on my radar discussion that FFTs are used in optics to "sharpen" images. I'm not even sure what that means in the context that I have. I was imagining some sort of sky imaging output from the FFT, but maybe that's unrealistic. If you have any suggestions for FFT analysis of this data, I'd like to hear them. I'm interested in quantifying variability over the array. Cheers.

Comment: What is your end goal? Maybe you could update the question with more detail on what you mean by quantifying variability. Do you want a map with the std deviation of each pixel (element of the array) within a time frame?

Comment: Before launching into an edit of the answer, I am trying to clarify: I think you are saying you have a grid of sensors, and some of them see less sunlight because of clouds. You think an FFT (after regridding of data onto an evenly spaced grid) would permit some "sharpening" ; in general this is true if you have an "aperture function" and you can do a deconvolution (which is a multiplication in Fourier space - which is why FFT can be useful). But unless you have such a function, and you explain how you want to use the data, it is impossible to give you any actionable help.